# Проверить с какого домена идет запрос

Tags: php

На страницу вставляется script и при заходе на страницу делается запрос к php файлу. Как определить, на какой странице выполняется запрос средствами php? То есть скрипт может быть установлен на любых доменах.

Comment: Уточните: есть некий JavaScript, который, как счётчик, ставят на многие страницы разных сайтов. И этот JS при загрузке страницы обращается к PHP, расположенному где - там же, у каждого на своём сервере, или у вас - на одном для всех центральном сервере?

Comment: в запросе к php файлу в скрипте  document.location передать.

Comment: sergiks, php файл расположен на одном, центральном сервере. Насчет  document.location можно и воспользоваться (я так понял передавать их через xmlhttprequest), но ищу другие методы.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript может узнать о том, на какой он странице только через свойство [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location#Location_object). Та же Яндекс.Метрика [так работает](http://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js), хотя код их счётчика на странице содержит ещё и уникальный ID под данный сайт/домен. Вы же вряд ли собираетесь раздавать уникальный JS для каждого из сайтов.

PHP может расчитывать либо на `HTTP_REFERER`, как указал [[@klopp](/users/6550/klopp)](/users/6550/klopp), либо на "слитый" javascript'ом location.

Я бы расчитывал на location, а `HTTP_REFERER` тоже сохранял, про запас : )

Comment: Я так понял через xmlhttprequest все это дело производить? Не будет ли это "долгим" методом?

Comment: Не будет, если выполните уже после загрузки страницы по событию `document.ready`. Вам ответ от php нужен в документе, или достаточно "отметиться"?

Answer (score 0):

Например, $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']. Но его может и не быть.

Comment: Нет, по данному параметру не получится проверить.